# String is not compatible with String enum

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I have this type:

```
export type BunionLevel = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';
```

then I have this class:

```
export class BunionLogger {

  level: BunionLevel;

  constructor(opts?: BunionOpts) {
    this.level = String((opts && (opts.level || opts.maxlevel) || maxLevel || '')).toUpperCase();
  }

}
```

and I get this transpilation error:

[image]

**Uhhh what am I supposed to do?** I am not sure how to proceed. I can do this:

```
this.level = <BunionLevels> String((opts && (opts.level || opts.maxlevel) || maxLevel || '')).toUpperCase();
```

but the cast seems unnecessary...?

as requested, `BunionOpts` looks like:

```
export interface BunionOpts {
  level?: BunionLevel
  maxlevel?: BunionLevel
  appName?: string
  name?: string
  fields?: object
}
```

Comment: What does `BunionOpts` look like ?

Comment: Thanks I just added that info

Comment: Is there a `BunionLevel` & `BunionLevels`?

Comment: Well from the code you posted, it looks like that String may not be a valid `BunionLevel` value; in fact if that's really the *exact* code it will never be.

Comment: Apart from the typo in "BunionLevel**s**", they don't look compatible - your string has cases for `null` and `''` for example. It also has `toUpperCase` while `BunionLevel` doesn't have a single case which has capital letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `String` function then the result of `String((opts && (opts.level || opts.maxlevel) || maxLevel || ''))` will be a `string` not a value of `BunionLevel`. Also since you provide the `''` as a default and you use `toUpper` the result will definitely not be a valid string for `BunionLevel`.

If you remove `String` and `toUpper` and provide a valid default it would all work:

```
this.level = (opts && (opts.level || opts.maxlevel)) || 'foo';
```

Comment: Exactly. And if you want the default value to still be `''`, you can add it to your union: `type BunionLevel = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz' | '';`